# Create triangular matrix in tensorflow

Tags: matrix, tensorflow

I want to create a N * N lower triangular matrix with a length N*(N+1)/2 vector. I find tensorflow has a function `tf.contrib.distributions.fill_triangular` that achieves my goal.

However when I give

```
from tensorflow.contrib.distributions import fill_triangular
```

it says

> cannot import name fill_triangular

My tensorflow version is 1.4.1. Can anyone let me know where is `fill_triangular` or how to create a N * N lower triangular matrix with a length  N*(N+1)/2 vector?

Comment: It appears that fill_triangular is only added in version 1.5?

Answer (score 2):

`fill_triangular` is currently only available in the master version of Tensorflow ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/fill_triangular)); it is not included even in the latest stable version 1.5 ([docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/api_docs/python/tf/distributions)), let alone 1.4.1.

You can build your matrix using [`numpy.tril_indices`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tril_indices.html#numpy.tril_indices); here is an example with N=3:

```python
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]) # this is your N*(N+1)/2 vector
tri = np.zeros((3,3))  # initialize an NxN zero matrix
tri[np.tril_indices(3, 0)] = a
tri
```

the result is

```python
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.]])
```